# Secure Java SOAP web service - Active Directory authentication Trust

Tags: java, soap, active-directory, trust

I want to build a secure web-service betweeen a Java producer and a Java consumer. I want to authenticate using Active Directory using the domain accounts that the producer and consumer are running under.

Could you give me an example of this?

(ie: AD trusted automated alternative to manual keystores.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Spring WS](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) and the and [security certificate authentication](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html#security-certificate-authentication), [7.2.2.1.3 JaasPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html#d0e4049), and [7.2.2.3.3 JaasCertificateValidationCallbackHandler](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html#d0e4049).

There are some examples that tie this together through additional research.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an open source library, http://spnego.sourceforge.net/protected_soap_service.html, that has an example of exactly what you are looking to do.

This open source project has an example on how to require authentication (basic auth or Kerberos/Integrated Windows Authentication) via servlet filter.

The project also has an example on how to create a soap client that needs to connect to a protected soap service.