# Well-supported Java ADSI wrapper library?

Tags: java, wrapper, jna, adsi

Does anyone know of a good wrapper for the Windows ADSI libraries for Java?

(I'm trying to avoid writing my own in JNA - and I'd like to use something standard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much in the way of well-supported libraries for ADSI-java exists out there.

If you want support and the substance of what you're trying to achieve - then Spring's Acegi library will assist your active directory authentication of your web-app: http://www.acegisecurity.org/

If you want an active directory authentication for your web service - then try this: 
[Secure Java SOAP web service - Active Directory authentication Trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325637/secure-java-soap-web-service-active-directory-authentication-trust) 
(again a Spring security based solution)

To purely wrap the ADSI library itself - you could use JNA:
https://github.com/twall/jna/

Other implementations out there include:

- Doing it via JNI (http://www.isocra.com/2005/05/adsi-from-java/) although trying to do this instead of JNA would be a waste of your time
- As an alternative to JNA - you might try this library: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/01/updates_on_com4.html

Answer (score 0):

Kosuke has a nice article on calling ADSI Activex/COM components via com4j, so you can query active directory.

https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2008/01/10/active-directory-authentication-hudson

Not sure how supported it is though.